# trying to insert database row into object

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert a database row into an object and I don't understand what is the problem here:(i can't see the output).

```
<body>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include("dash_class.php");
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("msordash");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$dashim=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dash");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dashim)) { 
    $dash=new dash($row["name"],$row["msg"],$row["msg_date"]);

    echo $dash->name;
}
?>

</body>
```

**the class code:**

```
class dash
{
public $name;
public $msg;
public $msg_date;

function __constractor($name,$msg,$msg_date){
$this->name=$name;
$this->msg=$msg;
$this->msg_date=$msg_date;}


}

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `dash` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a constraaaaaaaaaactor? :) Sorry  what is `constractor` to be exact?

```
function __constractor($name,$msg,$msg_date){
```

it should be

```
__construct()
```

Like

```
function __construct($name,$msg,$msg_date){
```

Comment: Thank You Hanky Panky! now it works!